# How to use combineByKey?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to get the same result of countByKey with combineByKey.

```
scala> ordersMap.take(5).foreach(println)
(CLOSED,1)
(PENDING_PAYMENT,2)
(COMPLETE,3)
(CLOSED,4)
(COMPLETE,5)
```

This is my input and i want to use combineByKey to get the output of countByKey.

Output from countByKey (correct)

```
PAYMENT_REVIEW 729
CLOSED 7556
SUSPECTED_FRAUD 1558
PROCESSING 8275
COMPLETE 22899
PENDING 7610
PENDING_PAYMENT 15030
ON_HOLD 3798
CANCELED 1428
```

I have used combineByKey

```
val combine = ordersMap.combineByKey(  x => 1 , (a:Int ,v) => a +1 , (a : Int,v : Int) => a +1  )
```

but i got unexpected result , i am not sure why.

Result from combineByKey

```
(PENDING_PAYMENT,7600)
(CLOSED,3878)
(CANCELED,699)
(PAYMENT_REVIEW,368)
(PENDING,3764)
(ON_HOLD,1896)
(PROCESSING,4100)
(SUSPECTED_FRAUD,773)
(COMPLETE,11372)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "but i got unexpected result , i am not sure why."? Please include the exception for future reference.

Comment: Hi @Jacek Laskowski , i was mistakenly adding the value from executors by using (a,b) => a+1 but that was wrong. It shoul be (a,b) => a+b , due to which i was getting wrong result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're applying the function wrong. The last function you pass to `combineByKey` needs to combine two values of the accumulator type (`C`) which were potentially computed on different executors. That's why the function name is called `mergeCombiners`.

Documentation:

```
combineByKey[C](createCombiner: (V) ⇒ C, 
                mergeValue: (C, V) ⇒ C, 
                mergeCombiners: (C, C) ⇒ C): RDD[(K, C)]
```

How you should apply `mergeCombiners`:

```
val combine = 
  ordersMap.combineByKey(_ => 1 , (a: Int, _) => a + 1, (a: Int, v: Int) => a + v)
```